# Using htaccess to redirect a directory to URL

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I want to redirect with .htaccess any of the following:

```
http://domain.com/folder
http://domain.com/folder/
http://domain.com/folder/index.html
http://domain.com/folder/index.php
```

to

```
http://another-domain.com/file.php?var=xyz
```

I did understand how to rewrite file-to-file or folder-to-folder, but I'm missing how to redirect from a folder to other domain's file URL

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Enable `mod_rewrite` and `.htaccess` through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your  `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^folder(/.*|)$ http://another-domain.com/file.php?var=xyz [L,NC,R=301]
```

#### Suggested Reading: [Apache mod_rewrite Introduction](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html)